# Haproxy unknown keyword bind *:80 in frontend section

Tags: haproxy, documentation

I compiled Haproxy LTS 2.2 version from source with this command:

```
make TARGET=linux-glibc USE_PCRE=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_ZLIB=1 USE_CRYPT_H=1 USE_LIBCRYPT=1
```

There was no error during compiling.
This is my Haproxy config:

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
    
    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

frontend http-in
        bind 192.168.123.40:80
        acl gerrit hdr(host) -i gerrit.example.local
        acl jenkins hdr(host) -i jenkins.example.local
        use_backend gerrit if gerrit
        use_backend jenkins if jenkins

backend gerrit
        server gerrit 127.0.0.1:8080

backend jenkins
        server jenkins 127.0.0.1:8081
```

When I'm checking config with `haproxy -c -q -V -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` command I'm getting following error:

```
[NOTICE] 226/130914 (35193) : haproxy version is 2.2.2
[NOTICE] 226/130914 (35193) : path to executable is /usr/sbin/haproxy
[ALERT] 226/130914 (35193) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:33] : unknown keyword 'bind 192.168.123.40:80' in 'frontend' section
[ALERT] 226/130914 (35193) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 226/130914 (35193) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

I checked documentation and it's allowed to use `bind` keyword in frontend section
[http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#bind (Alphabetically sorted keywords reference)](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#bind%20(Alphabetically%20sorted%20keywords%20reference))

More mindfuck achieved when I commenting out `bind` keyword in frontend section. Then error says:

`[WARNING] 226/132456 (36642) : config : frontend 'http-in' has no 'bind' directive. Please declare it as a backend if this was intended.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you used some other whitespace character that looks like a space, but isn't actually the normal space character, between `bind` and `192.168.123.40:80`. Try typing in the text again, but this time use a regular space (U+0020, ASCII 32).

Comment: holy fuck  it was it. I don't know how that whitespace got there.

Comment: Maybe you hit AltGr+spacebar? That seems to make a space that looks like a space but isn't, at least on Linux.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for info